# how log all queries of api in lumen 5.7

Tags: laravel, lumen

I need to see to all queries that executed in api.
I tried 3 ways but none of them work

1:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::listen(function ($query) {
     Log::info($query->sql, ['Bindings' => $query->bindings, 'Time' => $query->time]);
});
```

listen method is not existed.

2:

```
Event::listen('Illuminate\Database\Events\QueryExecuted', function ($query) {
    Log::debug($query->sql . ' - ' . serialize($query->bindings));
});
```

this one didn't work too.

3:

```
DB::connection("mysql2")->enableQueryLog();
DB::connection("mysql2")->getQueryLog();
```

I put 1 and 2 in `bootstrap/app.php` and third one in api controller.

> I should mention that i have different databases.

Is there other way?

Comment: Have you tried [laravel debugger](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)?

Comment: The calls to `listen` probably should be in a Service Provider's `boot` method ... but the `listen` method is on the Connection so you would need to define that listener on both connections

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI yes , I tried, but because of old php , compser and packages it is impossible to install debuger

Comment: @lagbox I tried connections for `listen` too, could you please explain me more? maybe I made mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the 3rd approach in [terminable middleware](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware#terminable-middleware) e.g.:

```
namespace Illuminate\Session\Middleware;

use Closure;

class LogQueries
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        DB::connection("mysql2")->enableQueryLog();
        return $next($request);
    }

    public function terminate($request, $response)
    {
        Log::info('Queries executed', DB::connection("mysql2")->getQueryLog());
        
    }
}
```

You can then register this in your `app/bootstrap.php` as:

```
$app->middleware([
   App\Http\Middleware\LogQueries::class
]);
```

This should enable the query log at the start of the request and then log all queries at the end. The downside is if you perform many large queries (large as in long query string) you will need to keep them in memory until the end of the request which may not be ideal.

Note: I don't fully recall the array structure of the query log so you may need to adjust the log step to work for your needs better.